# How to host a localhost site on domain?

Tags: wordpress

I’m a beginner and I installed a WordPress site locally.  I can access the site via localhost at `localhost:8888/ecproj`. I have a domain registered with GoDaddy and I would like to host this site using that domain but I don't understand the process. I already exported the site to a file using a WordPress plug-in. What else is necessary to import this file in order to host the site on my domain?

Comment: When the url dcc.godaddy.com/manage/dcc is acessed it redirects to dcc.godaddy.com/domains. So it seems that the page to manage the domain is not possible to access.

Comment: I do not recommend hosting a website from your local PC if you are a beginner. There is a large body of prerequisite knowledge you must acquire about hosting, security, and being a webmaster. Let godaddy handle it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost is a hostname that resolves to 127.0.0.1 which is the default loopback interface on all computers. It means "connect to myself". Thus, I assume you are testing the website locally on your computer. To get that page on to the greater internet you need to upload it to your host. Please refer to the internal documentation for godaddy and contact their support if you need help.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/moving-small-wordpress-sites-to-godaddy-6110